# How can update access rules of one module with using other module's access file in odoo 10?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-10

I am working on point of sale, created a new sub module depends on POS.
how can define access rules in child module / extension which updates main module's access file.

Comment: the access rules difine by classe not by module or submodule

Comment: Then you have not to add access file in your submodule, except if you 've added a new table

Comment: Is it possible if i inherit existing class without any additional fields to apply access rights rather than modifying pos security.csv and security.xml file ?

Comment: Yes of course!!!